# How to find accounts and pension in England with only name?

Tags: united-kingdom

My father in law has worked in England for several years but moved to Denmark (current residence) he has a bad memory and thereby also bad control over his assets. Can we in any way find out which accounts he has in England and how much pension he has available? I think we'll be able to manage if we get that far. What is the best actions to take?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Lawrence I think when OP says "we" that includes the person who is supposed to hold these accounts and pension rights.

Comment: @jcaron Good point. I'll delete my previous comment.

Comment: I'm not UK-based, but this might help with the accounts - [mylostaccount.org.uk](https://www.mylostaccount.org.uk/index.htm).

Comment: @Lawrence I'll try to see where mylostaccounts gets me.